# NetTopologySuite: How to convert Polygon into LineString?

Tags: geojson, nettopologysuite

I have a load of GeoJSON which represents roads that are defined as Polygons in the data. I wish to convert them into a simpler representation so as to reduce the amount of noise in the presentation.

Is there any way to do this using the NetTopologySuite?

Answer (score 1):

Polygons can be converted into LineString simply by obtaining his boundary:

```
IGeometry pol = ...;
IGeometry lineString = pol.Boundary;
```

Notice that if you have a polygon with holes, the boundary will return a MultiLineString for each part of the polygon. You will have to explode it afterwards to get simple LineStrings.